# How to resolve unit testcase error in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

When I am writing a unit test case for Component 2, I get this error:

> this.loginapp.addCustomValidation  is  not a function

**Component 1:**

```typescript
    component MainComponent {
        @viewChild('loginapp'):LoginComponent
    
        ngAfterViewInit(): void{
            this.loginapp.addCustomValidation('username','required','Enter username');
            this.loginapp.addCustomValidation('username','pattern','Enter username');
        }
    
    }
```

**Component 2:**

```typescript
    component MainComponent2 extends MainComponent   {
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your unit test code? It would help others help you troubleshoot. One thing I noticed is that you've spelled `@viewChild` with a lowercase `v` when it should be uppercase, but I'm assuming that's just a typo for this question post and not a direct copy of your app code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about `Component1` being rendered while running unit tests of `Component2`, you can use `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]`

Remove `Component2` from `declarations` in `TestBed.configureTestingModule` and add `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]`.

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
....
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    Component2,
    // Component1, Remove this declaration
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
});
```

`NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` basically ignores elements that Angular doesn't understand and treats them as dead html.

============= Edit ===========

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    Component2,
    Component1,
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
});
```

Try adding Compnent1 and LoginComponent

Comment: Failed: Component Component1 not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module. I got this error

Comment: That's strange, with `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`, that should not happen. Try adding Componet1 and LoginComponent to declarations. I have made an edit.